# How to fix not working vcpkg in Kali Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, poco-libraries, vcpkg

I have downloaded Poco using vcpkg. But It did'nt work in vscode. I have also installed integrate. I have done evrything what vcpkg offical site asked. I even added directory to Path, but none of them worked. Every time i write:

```
#include <Poco>
```

Program says cannot open source path, please update your include path. Many source path located in /usr/bin/include. I even try to add Poco to /usr/bin/include. But it didn't work

I searched it every where. My last hope is stackoverflow

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `tasks.json` you wrote in VSCode. Or are you using the CMakeTools or MakeFileTools extensions?

Comment: `#include <Poco>` is incomplete, there's nothing to be found there. You're either making a very basic mistake (see the [example code](https://pocoproject.org/)), or you're not providing enough information. If the latter, you need to re-read [ask], learn how to make a [mre], and then **edit** your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your workspace `settings.json` will make CMake Tools automatically use vcpkg for libraries:

```
{
  "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
  }
}
```

Or add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
```